# Does this Code Look Correct?

Tags: php, mysql

This code is supposed to update the database record for the given book. There is form that passes this function the rquired data and there are no errors in that form but I fear that I have formated my query to UPDATE MySQL incorrectly. Can someone verify this for me? I seem to always have trouble remember the formatting of a MySQL query string. If anyone has tips on how to remember it quickly without looking at documentation that would be greatly appreciated.

```
function saveBook ($ID, $Title, $Author, $Type, $Section, $AvailableMaterial)
{
    $query = "UPDATE Publications SET Title = '$Title', Author = '$Author', Section = '$Section', Type = '$Type', AvailableMaterial = '$AvailableMaterial' WHERE ID = '$ID'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
    die('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    return HEADER ("LOCATION: /lightBox/close.php");
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tested it to see if it works?

Comment: Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this code is not correct.

```
 $query = "UPDATE Publications SET `Title` = '".$Title."', `Author` = '".$Author."', `Section` = '".$Section."', `Type` = '".$Type."', `AvailableMaterial` = '".$AvailableMaterial."' WHERE `ID` = '".(int)$ID."'";
```

is better. type is a reserved key in mysql, so you need backtics.

And I assume you escape all your data before sending it to "savebook"

Comment: Yes John, everything is being escaped.I thank you for your response. It's not that I try to avoid docs, it's more the fact that I am a visual learner so to have someone give me an example is much more useful. @Matt Thank you for the link, I didn't know it existed (CodeExchange) and thank you for the heads up about the mysql_* deprecation.